# Returning rows that has matching record in another table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have Table Students with columns Student ID and Student Name. I also have Table Events with columns ID, Student ID and Event.

Now, i want to write a query that will return only rows from Students Table that has its Student ID present in Events Table.

I am running MySql 5+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

besides JOIN and IN you can also use EXISTS

```
SELECT * FROM Students s
WHERE EXISTS  (SELECT * 
                    FROM Events e
                    WHERE e.StudentID = s.StudentID)
```

Comment: ON SQl Server a join and exists will result in the same exact execution plan for this case

Comment: He's not using SQL Server. The question is tagged MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

Simple, inner join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Students.Id, Students.StudentName)
FROM Students
JOIN Events on Students.StudentId = Events.StudentId
ORDER BY Students.StudentName
```

Comment: Why the distinct on name? If two students have the same name 'John Smith', does this mean they are also the same person?

Comment: @Mark: Good eyes. The distinct needs to include the ID.

Comment: When i used the join it worked on my local mysql but when i uploaded the code to my web hosting, it generated an exception about too many joins coz i was already using two joins before adding a third one. but SQLMenace method worked on both local and hosting mysql.thx very much

Comment: I guess MySQL has a limit of 61 joins. Three is way too few to throw such exception

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Students
WHERE StudentID IN (SELECT StudentID 
                    FROM Events 
                    WHERE Events.StudentID = Students.StudentID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write `WHERE StudentId IN SELECT StudentId FROM Events`.  (Or at least you can in SQL Server)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.* FROM Students s INNER JOIN Events e ON e.StudentId = s.id;
```

Comment: This may return the same records multiple times

Answer (score 0):

```
select students.ID, students.name 
from students join events on students.id = events.studentID 
group by students.ID, students.name
```